# how to remove data from linkedlist in java

Tags: java, android, singly-linked-list

I am creating a demo shopping cart in android for this i am using Application class for saving data. I am unable to delete data from linkedlist. I am calling removeItem() function for android activity for removing selected item from the list but it is not working any one can help me.

```
    package in.co.santoshsharma.bookshopping;

import java.util.LinkedList;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.res.Configuration;

public class GlobalData extends Application{
    private String email;
    private String itemName;
    private int itemQuantity;
    private int itemCost;

    public GlobalData(){

    }
    public  GlobalData(String iName,int iQunt,int iCost) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.itemCost=iCost;
        this.itemName=iName;
        this.itemQuantity=iQunt;

    }




    public void setEmail(String mail)
    {
        this.email=mail;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }
    public String getItemName()
    {
        return itemName;
    }

    public int getItemCost()
    {
        return itemCost;
    }

    public int getItemQunt()
    {
        return itemQuantity;
    }



    LinkedList<GlobalData> list = new LinkedList<GlobalData>();

    public void setList(String iName,int iQunt,int iCost)
    {
        list.add(new GlobalData( iName, iQunt, iCost));
    }

    public LinkedList<GlobalData> getList()
    {
        return list;
    }
    public void removeItem(String iName,int iQunt,int iCost)
    {
        for(GlobalData data:list)
        {
            if(data.getItemName().equals(iName))
            {
                list.remove(itemName);
                //list.remove(iCost);
                //list.remove(iQunt);
            }
        }
    } 



}
```

Comment: Use an iterator to iterate through the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, override `equals()` method and use `itemName` attribute for the comparison

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o == null) return false;
  if (itemName == null) return false;
  if (o instanceOf String) return itemName.equals(o);
  else if (o instanceOf GlobalData) return ((GlobalData) o).itemName.equals(this.itemName);
  else return false;
}
```

Then, change your `removeItem()` method

```
public void removeItem(String iName) {
  list.remove(iName);
  // or uncomment line below to completely remove all matching elements
  // for (;;list.remove(iName)) {}
}
```

According to [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) `remove()` method of a `LinkedList` will call the `equals()` method of the supplied `Object` and compare it with every element in the list.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot operate in lists (add, remove... items) while you iterate on them. You have to use an Iterator

```
for(Iterator<EmpDedup> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    EmpDedup data = iter.next();
    if (data.getRecord() == rec1) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Refered from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10735435/1602230

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify a Collection using for-each loop. Use simple `for` loop or `while`.

> The for-each loop hides the iterator, so you cannot call remove.
>   Therefore, the for-each loop is not usable for filtering. Similarly it
>   is not usable for loops where you need to replace elements in a list
>   or array as you traverse it.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Generally, a collection named `list` storing elements of type `E` uses an iterator in the following way:

```
Iterator<E> iterator = list.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    <do something with iterator.next()>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a iterator to remove the element:

```
public void removeItem(String iName, int iQunt, int iCost) {
  Iterator<GlobalData> iterator = list.iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    GlobalData data = iterator.next();
    if (data.getItemName().equals(iName)) {
      iterator.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**-** You are Concurrently accessing and modifying the `Collection`, that can't be done from `For-Each` loop directly..

**-** Use `Iterator` to solve this problem.

```
LinkedList<GlobalData> q1 = new LinkedList<GlobalData>();

Iterator<GlobalData> iterator = q1.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()){

         GlobalData mp = iterator.next();

         if (mp.name.equals("xyz")){

             iterator.remove();    // You can do the modification here.
         }


 }
```