# Removing an object from a arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist with names, phone numbers and locations.

I would like to remove certain items from that array if possible

Is there anyway to remove the item once I have found it like I have tried below?

```
public void delete(String nameToDelete) 
{    
    for (Entry entry : Directory.entries) { 
        if (entry.name.equalsIgnoreCase(nameToDelete))
        {
            //remove(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099654/how-to-remove-data-from-linkedlist-in-java/13100020#13100020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reason?

Iterators returned by [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is `fail-fast` in nature.

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and `listIterator` methods are `fail-fas`t: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

### Where does this iterator Come from while I am not using it?

For enhanced for loop for collections `Iterator` gets used so you can not call remove method while you are iterating.

So your loop is same as below

```
for (Iterator<Entry> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ){
```

### What is the Solution Then ?

You can call `iterator.remove();` and change loop based on iterator explicitly rather than implicitly.

```
    String inputWord = "john";
    ArrayList<String> wordlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    wordlist.add("rambo");
    wordlist.add("john");
    for (ListIterator<String> iterator = wordlist.listIterator(); iterator
            .hasNext();) {
        String z = iterator.next();
        if (z.equals(inputWord)) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(wordlist.size());
```

### Now Where Can I Read more?

1. [The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)
2. [ArrayList Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Or just use `iterator()` instead of `listIterator()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Iterator` to remove the entry from your list. If you try to modify your `List` while iterating it through enhanced for-loop, it may throw a [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html), although this does not happen always, but there is not guarantee.

Here's how you can use `Iterator` for your List: -

```
Iterator<Entry> iterator = Directory.entries.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Entry entry = iterator.next();

    if (entry.name.equalsIgnoreCase(nameToDelete)) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Even in the `Iterator` you should remove the element using the `iterator.remove` method and not with the `list.remove` method, because that will not make a difference.

You can also use [**ListIterator**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) which gives you even more operations and methods to iterate the list. See the documentation for details.

To use `ListIterator`, you can create it like this: -

```
ListIterator<Entry> listIterator = Directory.entries.listIterator();
```

And rest of the code works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

What you would do is use `if entry.getKey().equals(nameToDelete)` to check if it's the one you want, then use the `remove()` method to remove that entry.

However you cannot do this inside of a `for()` loop iterating over the same collection you're modifying.  You will get a [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

See ["How to Avoid ConcurrentModificationException when using an Iterator"](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html).