# How to remove an object from a linked list in java

Tags: java, object

I have a linkedlist called seatList made up of Seat objects set up like so...

```
public class Seat {

    int row, col;
    char type;

    Seat(int row, int col, char type){
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.type = type;
    }

    String printSeat(){
        return "(" + row + ", " + col + ", " + type + ")";
    }

}
```

When i try to remove the seats with the same properties by creating a new seat object and storing it in a seperate linked list called collections, they do not get removed from the Linked List.

```
LinkedList<Seat> collection = new LinkedList();

    for (int q : indexToRemove){
        collection.add(new Seat(seatList.get(q).row, seatList.get(q).col, seatList.get(q).type));
    }

    for (Seat s : collection){
        if (seatList.contains(s)){
            println("true");
            seatList.remove(s);
        }

    }

    if (orders.get(indexes.get(index)).seatList.isEmpty()){
        orders.remove((int)indexes.get(index));
    }
```

Reason it is different: linked question talks about altering the list you are iterating as stated by csm_dev

Comment: you need to implement hashCode/equals/compareTo methods in Seat object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove a object from linked list in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735288/how-to-remove-a-object-from-linked-list-in-java)

Comment: The above linked question talks about altering the list you are iterating which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really don't need to create new objects to add to `collection` list, you can add objects from `seatList` and second `for` in you code snippet will remove objects from that list.

```
for (int q : indexToRemove){
    collection.add(seatList.get(q));
}
```

When you `check` weather list contains object or not, object's `equals()` method is used and you should implement it accordingly along with `hashCode()` method to get desired result.

Comment: doesn't a linkedlist readjust after removing an element so after removing one element from the linkedlist all indexes would change on all other elements?

Comment: this works until you remove more than one element at which it removes elements with past index. any way around this?

Comment: Yes you are right, it does. You should either override equals/hashCode or another not quite elegant solution is to replace old object in "seatList" with a newly created object that you added to "collection". After that your contains check will work. 
Do you really need to create new objects when adding to collection? If not, you can add objects from "seatList" to "collection": collection.add(seatList.get(q)); After that, second `for` will remove them from the original list.

Comment: just tried the last part works like a charm thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To remove object from list you have to use Iterator and call remove() on iterator an example :

```
    Iterator<Seat> collection = seatList.iterator();
    while (collection.hasNext()) 
    {
       Seat element = collection.next();

       //some condition on your object "element"

        collection.remove();
      }
```

and don't foget to define hashCode/equals methodes logic to compare your Seat objects

Answer (score 1):

**You have to use Iterator for this**:

```
Scanner scr= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Seat Row number to delete: ");
int row = scr.nextInt();

for (Iterator<Seat> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {

    Seat data = iter.next();

    if (data.getRow() == row) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

You have to add setters and getters in your been class.

Comment: still no dice with this solution. getter and setter are not needed in seat class

Comment: for my solution it required

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList & other list implementations uses equals() method to check if the object is present in the list. Since you don't have equals() method implemented, java will use the implementation provided by Object class, which is very crude & not work for you.

You need to implement equals() method & give jvm a way to see if 2 objects of seat are same.